# пожалуйста разобраться с числами

Tags: python

Python. помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться до конца, вернее с ошибками
например, вводимые числа:
200, 290, 180, 400, 340, 150, 440, 650, 300, 210.. их может быть и больше

нужно определить является ли число больше при сравнивании со суммой чисел слева и справа. так нужно сделать со всеми. Результат должен быть:
2.290
8.650

сейчас выводит одно число, но нужно сравнить весь список подобно и потом соединить с функцией 'enumerate'

```
income = input(" Enter numbers: ")
numbers = [int(d) for d in income.split(',')]

current_number = 0

for index in range(1, len(numbers) - 1):
numbers = (numbers[index - 1], numbers[index], numbers[index + 1])
summary = numbers[index - 1] + numbers[index + 1]
item = numbers[index]
if item >= summary == 0:
current_number += 1

print(item)

for index, item in enumerate(item, start=2):
print(f"index:{index},item:{item}")
```

Comment: Я не понял, что нужно сделать, и почему в ответе такие числа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numbers = [200, 290, 180, 400, 340, 150, 440, 650, 300, 210]

print('\n1 способ')
for i, x in enumerate(numbers):
    if 0 < i < (len(numbers) - 1) and numbers[i - 1] < x > numbers[i + 1]:
        print(f'{i + 1}.{x}')

print('\n2 способ')
for i, x in enumerate(numbers[1:-1]):
    if numbers[i] < x > numbers[i + 2]:
        print(f'{i + 2}.{x}')

print('\n3 способ')
for i, (y, x, z) in enumerate(zip(numbers, numbers[1:], numbers[2:])):
    if y < x > z:
        print(f'{i + 2}.{x}')
```

```
1 способ
2.290
4.400
8.650

2 способ
2.290
4.400
8.650

3 способ
2.290
4.400
8.650
```

Comment: )спасибо!! ошибку понято. enumerate можно рассматривать как range (диапазон определённых чисел). не обязательно чтобы там всегда было именно 'range'.

Comment: Код интересный, но в чём задача я так и не понял. Там же фигурирует слово "сумма", а тут никакой суммы нет.

Comment: @CrazyElf описания задач далеко не всегда идеальные. В данном случае я ориентировался на ожидаемый результат, который тоже не идеален, но по двум точкам можно построить гипотезу.

Comment: @АлексейР Да, я понял, что ориентация была на вывод, мой вопрос больше к автору топика )